# ¿Qué hace exactamente la función?

Tags: javascript

La siguiente función convierte un número binario a uno decimal:

```
function binTodecimal(binstr){



    return parseInt((binstr + '')
    .replace(/[^01]/gi, ''), 2);
}
console.log(binTodecimal('110011'));
```

¿Alguien me podría diseccionar el código y decirme qué hace en cada momento? Especialmente aquí:

```
.replace(/[^01]/gi, ''), 2);
```

Answer (score 9):

Tienes la función:

- `replace` la cual en conjunto con una expresión regular van a tratar de encontrar lo siguiente:

  - Lo que esta entre corchetes `[]` es un onjunto de datos a identificar como patrón en el valor pasado como argumento, el caracter `^` al inicio indica que buscará todo aquello que no cumpla el patrón señalado en los corchetes
  - Las banderas de `g` indican una búsqueda por encontrar todas las conincidencias en el valor pasado, es decir va a buscar el patrón de `01` en todo el argumento dado a la función
  - La bandera `i` va a encontrar todas las coincidencias del patrón sin importar por ejemplo si el texto pasado esta en mayúsculas o minúsculas *(aunque para este caso particular no le encuentro al menos yo utilidad alguna)*

De hecho puedes quitarle:

- Las comillas `''` que están como segundo argumento de la función `replace`
- Las comillas `''` que se están concatenando

Ahora el número 2 en específico que aparece como segundo argumento de la función `parseInt()` indica que:

Dicho método tiene los siguientes argumentos:

- Un número como primer argumento
- La base matemática que representa a la cadena, en este caso es una base binaria.

Por ejemplo:

```
console.log(parseInt("11", 2))
```

Tendrá una salida como:

> 3

Dado que si revisas la estructura yo solo habilite en 1 a los primeros 2 números del octeto así:

```
11111111 = 128
00000011 = 3
```

Donde de derecha a izquierda cada posición vale lo siguiente:

```
Posición    Valor
   1          1
   2          2
   3          4
   4          8
   5         16
   6         32
   7         64
   8        128
```

**Referencias**

- [Regex flags](http://xregexp.com/flags/)
- [parseInt base](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt)

Comment: Según yo, el carácter `^` dentro `[^01]` es una "negada de carácter", entonces `replace(/[^01]/gi, '')` reemplazará todo lo que NO sea "01" por "" (nada)

Comment: @ftorres me guíe por la tabla de flags de Mozilla Developer [justo aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp), pero si me equivoque edito para enmendar el fallo

Comment: Revisa este texto, sacado de ahí mismo " 
Un set de caracteres negado ó complementario. Esto significa que, encuentra todo aquello que no se encuentre dentro del set especificado dentro de los corchetes. Se puede especificar un rango de caracteres (continuos) por medio de un guión. Por ejemplo, [^abc] es idéntico a [^a-c]. Ambos sets encuentran la letra inicial "r" en la palabra "brisket" y la letra inicial "h" en la palabra "chop"."

Comment: Dame oportunidad de revisar y en cuanto me haga un espacio corrijo

Answer (score 5):

La función "convierte" un número binario a decimal.

```
//El parámetro binstr por lo que noto, puede ser un string o number
function binTodecimal(binstr){

//En esta parte, se convierte a decimal usando parseInt(string, 2) el segundo argumento (2) es la base.
//En la parte 
(binstr + '') 
//Sí el argumento dado en binstr es de tipo number, entonces con + '' se convierte a string, esto asegura que la función "replace" esté disponible

//Y por último, la función replace con la expresión regular /[^01]/gi buscará todo lo que NO sea 01, osea que de cierta manera "limpia" el valor de binstr.
return parseInt((binstr + '')
.replace(/[^01]/gi, ''), 2);
```

Básicamente recibe un parámetro y se asegura de que se pueda usar "replace" y que el valor sea valido para poder ejecutar `parseInt` y retornar un valor.